# Help with divergence and Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

If we start with a vector field which has continuous first partial derivatives and if we then we calculate the line integral of the field around some closed loop and then apply Stokes' theorem to convert it into a surface integral and then if we apply divergence theorem will the answer always be zero since div (curl F))=0 ?

Comment: How does the curl arise?

Answer (score 0):

What if, like $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$, the vector field has some divergence?

Comment: Its divergence is 3

Comment: Right.  So the integral shouldn't be $0$.  That's my point.